# Razor Intellesense breaks when changing output path

Tags: visual-studio, razor

I'm making a plugin framework and to aid development i am changing the output path of each plugin to the shell project. However, in doing so it breaks razor intellesense in any .cshtml files in that particular project.

Is there any way around this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the output path back to default (\bin)

and set up a post build event

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\bin" "$(SolutionDir)Frontline_UPF\Modules\$(ProjectName)" /i /s /y /q
```

I couldnt use $(TargetDir) since it added a \ to the end and that prevented xcopy from working.